# Firebase admin SDK: getUserByEmail fails for facebook

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have enabled facebook, google and email/password options in my firebase console.

(1): If a facebook user logs-in and chooses to disclose his email, after successful login the firebase console shows his record for the email. Also, through Admin SDK I am able to get the User record using the getUserByEmail method.

[image]

So far this is fine. 
(2) But when the user does not disclose his email, the firebase does not have his email info (which is expected).

[image]

[image]

The problem appears if the user deletes the app from facebook (settings > apps & websites) and retries the register action or login.

[image]

After deleting the app from settings in facebook, user will again have the choice to disclose his email or not. If he chooses to disclose his email. the same record which was created during (2) seems to get updated with his email. Firebase console shows the record if I query for this email.

But through admin SDK, getUserByEmail does not return any User record corresponding to this email. Is this a bug in firebase admin SDK or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have raised an issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/482)

Seems the behaviour is expected. Also, a feature request was also raised for api to search with email.